# Cannot save customer programatically

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, import, custom

I tried to write a external script for customer import. I get sample customer data from csv file and put them into an array. it was success, and I can see all the data from the array.

Then I tried to add customer programatically. I use Magestore's article as a reference, [here](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/create-customer-add-address-programmatically/).

First I tried using given sample data and it was a success. Customer is added and I can see new customer from magento admin.

But when I tried to use a foreach loop to run same process for my list of customers (I have 10 sample customers in my csv file.), it gives me an exception.

For example, if I use `$customer->setEmail('email@gmail.com');` it will be added and no error. but if I use my array, `$customer->setEmail($customerImport[0]);` it shows the exception.

Here is my code, can please someone tell me what's the wrong and how to fix this?

```
<?php 

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$customerImport = getCustomerImport();

function getCustomerImport(){

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$file = 'tesseract/import/customer.csv';  //CSV file path
$arrResult = array();
$headers = false;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if (empty($handle) === false) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if (!$headers) {
$headers[] = $data;
} else {
$arrResult[] = $data;
}
}
fclose($handle);
}


try{
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
// $store = $storeManager->getStore();  // Get Store ID
// $storeId = $store->getStoreId();

foreach ($arrResult as $customerImport) {
// Necessary data from csv
$email  = (string)$customerImport[0];
$websiteName    = $customerImport[1];
$storeName  = $customerImport[2];
$confirmationReq    = $customerImport[3];
$firstName  = $customerImport[4];
$groupId    = $customerImport[5];
$lastName   = $customerImport[6];
$middleName = $customerImport[7];
$userPrefix = $customerImport[8];
$storeId    = $customerImport[9];
$userSuffix = $customerImport[10];
$userUpdatedAt  = $customerImport[11];
$websiteId  = $customerImport[12];
$userPassword   = $customerImport[13];

// Instantiate object (this is the most important part)

$customer = $customerFactory->create();

$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

$customer->setEmail($email);

$customer->setFirstname($firstName);

$customer->setLastname($lastName);

$customer->setPassword($userPassword);

$customer->save();

echo 'Create customer successfully'.$customer->getId();

}

}
catch(Exception $eXp){
echo 'Something failed on customer import '. PHP_EOL;
print_r($eXp);

}

} //end of the function

?>
```

Comment: What exception are you getting ?

Comment: Can you add the exception here, it'll easy to understand the issue.

Comment: @LazyCoder here is the paste **https://justpaste.it/4nlrf**

Comment: @Lasantha please see here **https://justpaste.it/4nlrf**

Comment: @OCdave - check "$customerImport[0] " is an object or just a line of text ?

Comment: @OCdave Or validate the text using isset() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the data in the csv file,

You must have some empty cells all that are causing issue for saving customer.

```
1.fill empty fields
2.required fields should be validated and 
3.check the each field with `isset()`.
```

Then check and comment your result here.

Comment: I think error was because I have some empty fields on my csv. it was sample data and some fields were empty. and required fields being empty may have been the reason.